# Database connectivity in WCF Service

Tags: c#, database, wcf

I am creating a WCF Service.
It receives data from a iPhone App.
When the user sends data from their iPhone I need to save the data
into our Database useing WCF Service. 
In my WCF application I am creating a class and wrote the following code.

```
string connstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ToString();
string SQLstr = "myStoredProc1";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);
```

Intellisense is giving error for `(constr, SQLstr)`

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or
>   property.

Why I am getting this error. I see a lot of examples online with the same code.
Then why its giving error for my application. Is it because this class is in a WCF application.

Comment: It has nothing to do with WCF. It's a _compiler_ error, and the compiler doesn't know anything about WCF. It means what it says!

Comment: the method you have this code in seems to be static. Change it to Instance method and it should work. If this doesnt fix the problem, please post entire code.

Comment: Its not static method. Its not in a method. here is the entire code. using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WCFRESTService100
{
    public class myclass
    {
         string conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ToString();
        string SQLstr = "myStoredProc1";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SDconn);
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);
    }
}

Comment: add this in the method: SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SDconn); SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn);

Comment: Please post all of this code in your question. You are allowed to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it sould look like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WCFRESTService100 
{ 
    public class myclass 
    { 
        string conn1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ToString(); 
        string SQLstr = "myStoredProc1"; 

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SDconn);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLstr, conn); 


        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks for the info and really appreciated your time and help.